# Display toolbar in child classes from BaseActivity

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem when trying to display my toolbar in child classes it never shows. I debugged the application and toolbar is always null. I tried setting the parent class (BaseActivity) to abstract and used an abstract int to get the layout ID but that did not work toolbar was still null. I have a navigation drawer which works fine I can slide it out from the side but there is no toolbar which means the hamburger icon never gets shown either. This line tends to give me NullPointerException error: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

**BaseActivity**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    SharedPrefs sharedPrefs;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    // Make sure to be using androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle version.
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        sharedPrefs = new SharedPrefs(this);
        if (sharedPrefs.loadDarkModeState()) {
            setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        } else setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

        sharedPrefs = new SharedPrefs(this);
        if (sharedPrefs.loadUserLoggedInState()) {
            sharedPrefs.setUserLoggedInState(true);
        } else sharedPrefs.setUserLoggedInState(false);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        configureToolbarNavDrawer();

        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    }

    public void configureToolbarNavDrawer() {

        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        // Find the drawer view
        mDrawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        // Setup toggle to display hamburger icon with nice animation
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerToggle.syncState();

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (currentUser == null && !sharedPrefs.loadUserLoggedInState()) { // If current user isn't logged in make them login
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        // NOTE: Make sure you pass in a valid toolbar reference.  ActionBarDrawToggle() does not require it
        // and will not render the hamburger icon without it.
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Start of Navigation bar selection/onclick
    public void onNavigationItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.linear_nav_header:
            case R.id.nav_now_showing:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cinemas:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, CinemaActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_airing_today:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AiringTodayActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_saved_films:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SaveLaterActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                sharedPrefs.setUserLoggedInState(false);
                mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                Toast.makeText(this, "You are Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                break;
        }
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }
    //End
```

**Toolbar.xml**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarColor"
    app:titleTextColor="?attr/actionBarColorText"
    android:iconTint="?attr/titleColor" />
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements ServiceListener{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
}
```

**Themes**

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <!-- Light/Day theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <!-- Dark/Night theme. -->
    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is null because you have set up the toolbar but haven't set the layout for the activity yet.

Try moving `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to BaseActivity like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sharedPrefs = new SharedPrefs(this);
    if (sharedPrefs.loadDarkModeState()) {
        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
    } else setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

    sharedPrefs = new SharedPrefs(this);
    if (sharedPrefs.loadUserLoggedInState()) {
        sharedPrefs.setUserLoggedInState(true);
    } else sharedPrefs.setUserLoggedInState(false);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // HERE
    configureToolbarNavDrawer();
    ...
}
```

And don't forget to remove it from `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements ServiceListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }
}
```

---

so, after discussing further this is the code that should meet your expectation

First, remove `configureToolbarNavDrawer()` from `BaseActivity`

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        sharedPrefs = new SharedPrefs(this);
        if (sharedPrefs.loadDarkModeState()) {
            setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        } else setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    
        sharedPrefs = new SharedPrefs(this);
        if (sharedPrefs.loadUserLoggedInState()) {
            sharedPrefs.setUserLoggedInState(true);
        } else sharedPrefs.setUserLoggedInState(false);
    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        configureToolbarNavDrawer(); // Remove this line
        ...
    }
```

Then, change your `configureToolbarNavDrawer()` function in `BaseActivity` to this

```
    public void configureToolbarNavDrawer(Toolbar toolbar) {
        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ...
    }
```

Lastly, call `configureToolbarNavDrawer()` in `MainActivity` after `setContentView`

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements ServiceListener{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) // Add this line
        configureToolbarNavDrawer(toolbar) // Add this line
   }
}
```

Comment: The idea is that I have multiple activities which all need the toolbar. I had this code duplicated into multiple activities but its not ideal to have the code duplicated when it can be put into a single file and accessed by extending each class. I have a base_layout with the toolbar for BaseActivity but using that does not help. Is it possible to get the toolbar from child activities?

Comment: ohh i see, yes I agree with the code duplication concept. Hmm, try adding toolbar Id parameter in `configureToolbarNavDrawer()` so in child class you simply call this function and pass toolbar Id as the parameter. I think this is going to work

Comment: Ok so do I then call the method in child class rather than BaseActivity?

Comment: Yes that's correct, remove `configureToolbarNavDrawer()` from `BaseActivity` and move it to the child classes in `onCreate`

Comment: Ok thanks so I did
```Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        configureToolbarNavDrawer(toolbar);```
in the child class and
```public void configureToolbarNavDrawer(Toolbar toolbar) {

        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        this.toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(this.toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}```
in BaseActivity. I can open the child activity but the toolbar does not appear it does however now have an ID it is no longer null.

Comment: I had contentView set to activity_base in BaseActivity without that toolbar is null

Comment: I think you can remove `this.toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` line in `BaseActivity` so directly use the child toolbar `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Answer (score 2):

You can move the `setContentView` in the `BaseActivity` using something like:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(getLayoutId());

       //all the code
    }
    
    protected abstract @LayoutRes int getLayoutId(); 
}
```

Then in your `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements ServiceListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //...
    
   }
    protected @LayoutRes int getLayoutId(){
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }
}
```